# The `router-link-active` classname unexpectedly applies to a <router-link> which is pointing to `/`

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have set up very basic routing on a Vue project using `vue-router`.

The [`router-link-active` classname](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) gets applied as expected to the active root. In the following gif, that would be 'Foo' when `/foo` is active, etc.

[image: vue-router-router-link-active-unexpected]

However, the link to 'Hello world' also has the `router-link-active` classname.

Why does it get applied and how can I ensure it's only active when I am on `/` (`localhost:8080`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `exact` prop to your `"/"` route

> The default active class matching behavior is inclusive match. For
>   example,  will get this class applied as long as
>   the current path starts with /a.
>
> One consequence of this is that  will be **active
>   for every route!** To force the link into "exact match mode", use the
>   exact prop:

```
<!-- this link will only be active at / -->
    <router-link to="/" exact>
```

Here is what you need: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg71rtub/)